# Offset rotation matrix

Tags: numpy, rotation, linear-algebra, offset

I'm working with 2 imu's. I need to offset all frames with the first frame from the sensor. I have created a fictive scenario, where I precisely know the rotation and the wanted result. I need the two sensors to show the same result when their initial (start) orientation is subtracted.

```
import numpy as np
# Sensor 0,1 and 2 start orientation in degrees
s0_x = 30
s0_y = 0
s0_z = 0

s1_x = 0
s1_y = 40
s1_z = 0

s2_x = 10
s2_y = 40
s2_z= -10

# Change from start frame 1

x1 = 20
y1 = 10
z1 = 0

# Change from start frame 2

x2 = 60
y2 = 30
z2 = 30

GCS= [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
sensor0 = [[s0_x, s0_y, s0_z], [s0_x, s0_y, s0_z], [s0_x, s0_y, s0_z]]
sensor1 = [[s1_x, s1_y, s1_z],  [s1_x + x1, s1_y + y1, s1_z + z1],[s1_x + x1 + x2, s1_y + y1+ y2, s1_z + z1+ z2]]
sensor2 = [[s2_x, s2_y, s2_z], [s2_x + x1, s2_y + y1, s2_z + z1], [s2_x + x1+ x2, s2_y + y1+ y2, s2_z + z1+ z2]]


def Rot_Mat_X(theta):
    r = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],[0,np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]]) 
    return r

# rotation the rotation matrix around the Y axis (input in deg)
def Rot_Mat_Y(theta):
    r = np.array([[np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),0,np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
                   [0,1,0],
                   [-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),0,np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]]) 
    return r


# rotation the rotation matrix around the Z axis (input in deg)
def Rot_Mat_Z(theta):
    r = np.array([[np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),0],
                   [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),0],
                   [0,0,1]]) 
    return r



# Creating the rotation matrices
r_sensor0 = []
r_sensor1= []
r_sensor2= []
for i in range(len(sensor1)):
    r_sensor1_z = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_X(sensor1[i][0]),GCS)
    r_sensor1_zy = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_Y(sensor1[i][1]),r_sensor1_z)
    r_R_Upperarm_medial_zyx = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_Z(sensor1[i][2]),r_sensor1_zy )
    r_sensor1.append(r_R_Upperarm_medial_zyx )
    r_sensor2_z = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_X(sensor2[i][0]),GCS)
    r_sensor2_zy = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_Y(sensor2[i][1]),r_sensor2_z )
    r_sensor2_zyx = np.matmul(Rot_Mat_Z(sensor2[i][2]),r_sensor2_zy )
    r_sensor2.append(r_sensor2_zyx )


r_start_sensor1 = r_sensor1[0]
r_start_sensor2 = r_sensor2[0] 

r_offset_sensor1 = []
r_offset_sensor2 = []
for i in range(len(sensor0)):
    r_offset_sensor1.append(np.matmul(np.transpose(r_start_sensor1),r_sensor1[i]))
    r_offset_sensor2.append(np.matmul(np.transpose(r_start_sensor2),r_sensor2[i]))


# result: 
r_offset_sensor1[0] = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
r_offset_sensor1[1] = [[0.984,0.059,0.163],[0,0.939,-0.342],[-0.173,0.336,0.925]]
r_offset_sensor1[2] = [[0.748,0.466,0.471],[0.086,0.635,-0.767],[-0.657,0.615,0.434]]

r_offset_sensor2[0] = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
r_offset_sensor2[1] = [[0.984,0.086,0.150],[-0.03,0.938,-0.344],[-0.171,0.334,0.926]]
r_offset_sensor2[2] = [[0.748,0.541,0.383],[-0.028,0.603,-0.797],[-0.662,0.585,0.466]]
```

I expect the result of sensors 1 and 2 to be equal for all frames but it doesn't? And they should be:

```
frame[0] = [1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]
frame[1] = [0.984,0,0.173],[0.059,0.939,-0.336],[-0.163,0.342,0.9254]
frame[2] = [0.750,-0.433,0.50],[0.625,0.216,-0.750],[0.216,0.875,0.433]
```

Comment: Please define your variables, give some (working or expected to work) code, and the expected output..

Comment: Hi, Daniel thanks for the comment, I have updated the question. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: Instead of defining the terms you had, you just added dozens more.  Code you give to us to test need to be runnable, we don't have `JAF.Rot_Mat_#()` functions to test with.
Based on the original data it seemed like your implementation for calculating the Euler angles from the rotation matrix and vice versa was flawed.  Maybe a rounding error?  I can't tell without the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the code so it is now runnable. It might be a rounding error, however if I remove the rotation around x axis it result in the correct orientation. But I do have x rotation in the real scenario so I need to find the right solution.

Comment: Euler angles don't add that way, so your expected result isn't true (for angles other than infintesimally small ones anyway).  The fact that Euler angles aren't commutative (so, non-intuitively,  `a + b - a /= b`) is precisely why one must use rotation matrices or quaternions to compose the resultant of two 3D rotations.  Those angle formulations *are* commutative through multiplication.

Comment: The reason why it works with two angles is because double-angle formulations (like longitude and latitude) *are* commutative until the system gimbal locks (i.e. once you cross over the north or south pole).

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for your answere. It make sanse. Do you know a method on how I can create a rotation matrix there isn't affected by this and I still know the orientation? I need it to test my following math.

Comment: If your following math is based on the assumption that Euler angles compose, it's probably wrong.  If there was an easily comprehensible way to compose angles that worked, they wouldn't make video game designers learn quaternions.

Comment: Good point. Not the answer I had hoped for but helpful. I do have rotation matrices all the way though, I just need a way to test and make sure the computations was correct. But it seems difficult.